# Can anyone tell me any cloud operating system?

Tags: operating-system

I have to work on my thesis for cloud operating systems and their security. But I don't know any cloud operating system. Can anyone tell me any cloud operating system I can write about?

I don't know the difference between  cloud operating systems and cloud computing platforms. I confuse these two always...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ambiguity in the term *cloud operating system*.  It might be interpreted as an operating system that is available on computers which are part of a *cloud-like network cluster*; in which case linux, macos, windows, ... are all candidates.

It might be interpreted as an operating system that runs *across* a cloud; which would be a system that treated entire computers as entities to dispatch work to, replicate, allocate, etc...   Very much analogous to what a traditional operating system might do with processes or threads.

An example of the later would be kubernetes, or k8s if you want to be hip.  Kubernetes describes itself as an orchestrater (sp?) in that it takes work described by a set of constraints, sets up various cloud components to do the work, possibly replicated, monitors and controls the components, then cleans up when the work is complete.

There are several orchestration platforms available besides k8s.